# Resizing SVG in HTML?

Tags: html, svg

I have an SVG file inside HTML, and one of the things I've heard about the format is that it doesn't get all pixelated when you zoom in on it.

I know with a JPEG or whatever I could have it stored as a 50 by 50 icon, then actually display it as a (rather pixelated) 100 by 100 thumbnail (or 10 by 10), by manually setting the height and width in the image_src tag.

However, SVG files seem to be used with object/embed tags, and changing the height or width of THOSE just results in more space being allocated for the picture.

Is there any way to specify that you want an SVG image displayed smaller or larger than it actually is stored in the file system?

Answer (score 293, accepted):

Open your `.svg` file with a text editor (it's just XML), and look for something like this at the top:

```
<svg ... width="50px" height="50px"...
```

Erase width and height attributes; the defaults are 100%, so it should stretch to whatever the container allows it.

Comment: Yes that's right, but you also need to add a 'viewBox' attribute (e.g viewBox="0 0 50 50" in your 50x50px example), otherwise the content might not scale properly (will depend on the container dimensions).

Scour will do this for you automatically, http://www.codedread.com/scour/.

Comment: Hooray! That helped! I already had things at 100% in the file, it turns out, but the view box was the key! Thank you both!

Comment: In case it's not obvious to anyone else, 'viewBox' is case sensitive. Also, the first two coordinates are the upper-left corner if you're cropping the image, and the second two coordinates are the width and height *before* scaling.

Comment: Note that both <div style="width: 50px;height: 50px"><svg viewBox="0 0 1000 1000">...</svg></div> and <svg viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" style="width: 50px; height: 50px" >...</svg> will work.

Comment: To complement the answers from @ErikDahlström and widged, you can go to the official site of [Developers Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox) and see the full documentation for viewBoxes. The 4 values are min-x, min-y, width and height, latter 2 can accept negative parameters.

Answer (score 69):

Try these:

1. Set the **missing viewbox** and fill in the height and width values of the set height and height attributes in the svg tag
2. Then scale the picture simply by **setting the height and width** to the **desired percent** values. Good luck.
3. Set a fixed aspect ratio with `preserveAspectRatio="X200Y200 meet` (e.g. 200px), but it's not necessary

e.g.

```
 <svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   width="10%" 
   height="10%"
   preserveAspectRatio="x200Y200 meet"
   viewBox="0 0 350 350"
   id="svg2"
   version="1.1"
   inkscape:version="0.48.0 r9654"
   sodipodi:docname="namesvg.svg">
```

Answer (score 39):

you can resize it by displaying svg in image tag and size image tag i.e.

```
<img width="200px" src="lion.svg"></img>
```

Comment: To me this is the best answer as it does not require editing the svg file.

Comment: This won't work if you're going for a responsive layout

Answer (score 37):

I have found it best to add `viewBox` and `preserveAspectRatio` attributes to my SVGs. The viewbox should describe the full width and height of the SVG in the form `0 0 w h`:

```
<svg preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="0 0 700 550"></svg>
```

Comment: Doing this as well as adding `width="100%"` and `height="100%"` worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 26):

Use the following code:

```
<g transform="scale(0.1)">
...
</g>
```

Comment: This doesn't work without additional considerations. The space for the image will be allocated to the page, however the image will appear as only 10% of the available space in the top left corner leaving the rest blank. This solution will only work with changes implemented in whatever displays the SVG image

Answer (score 12):

Changing the width of the container also fixes it rather than changing the width and height of source file.

```
.SvgImage img{ width:80%; }
```

---

This fixes my issue of re sizing svg . you can give any % based on your requirement.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example of getting the bounds using `svg.getBox()`:
https://gist.github.com/john-doherty/2ad94360771902b16f459f590b833d44

At the end you get numbers that you can plug into the svg to set the viewbox properly.  Then use any css on the parent div and you're done.

```
 // get all SVG objects in the DOM
 var svgs = document.getElementsByTagName("svg");
 var svg = svgs[0],
    box = svg.getBBox(), // <- get the visual boundary required to view all children
    viewBox = [box.x, box.y, box.width, box.height].join(" ");

    // set viewable area based on value above
    svg.setAttribute("viewBox", viewBox);
```

Comment: if only you could learn to wrap this into a method

Answer (score 3):

Remove `height` and `width` attributes in the svg element. Add a `viewBox` attribute, for example `viewBox 0 0 100 100`, then use plain old CSS `height` or `width` to scale the svg element.

**NOTE: the viewBox attribute is case sensitive. If you use a lowercase b it will not work.**

```css
.fifty{
height: 50px
}
.hundred{
height: 100px
}
```

```html
<h3>50x50</h3>
<section>
<svg class="fifty" viewBox="0 0 100 100"><path d="m18.75 36-2.15-2.15 9.9-9.9-9.9-9.9 2.15-2.15L30.8 23.95Z" fill="black"></path></svg>
</section>
<h3>100x100</h3>
<section>
<svg class="hundred" viewBox="0 0 100 100"><path d="m18.75 36-2.15-2.15 9.9-9.9-9.9-9.9 2.15-2.15L30.8 23.95Z" fill="black"></path></svg>
</section>
```