# SVG Dynamic resizing

Tags: javascript, html, svg

Does anyone know I can dynamically resize an svg image so it fits within a container?? I find that the images I have overflows. What I want is a way to resize it so it doesn't overflow. 
Any response is appreciated. I have also tried setting the width and the height to 100%

Comment: Provide your code as a basis to work on.

Comment: repeat question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3120739/resizing-svg-in-html

Comment: my code is a lot. I literally have to send you the folder. I can take a snapshot of how it looks. will that help? I tried setting the width and height to 100% like the link above suggested

Comment: @k.ken posted an answer with an example of what might work for you.

Answer (score 15):

Okay, so the easiest way of doing dynamic widths is just to provide a percentage value for `width` or/and `height`. You can find my example in a fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/VDKwy/

So the key part is either leaving out the `width` and `height` properties of off the svg element, or

```
<svg width="100%" height="100%"></svg>
```

And then using percentage value for inner elements like so:

```
<rect x="10%" y="10%" width="80%" height="80%" style="fill:blue;stroke-width:5; stroke:black" />
```

Comment: This is an example of how my container looks. The expressions image is an svg. Here is a link to a snapshot of it: http://imgur.com/3Yw6v

Comment: So if you provide dynamic width&height on that it's not fitting you required space?

Comment: So you need to provide dynamic values for your container div and your inside elements of the svg container. Either way it's super difficult to understand why it overflows from just an image.

Comment: yeah I understand. I thought another option will be available

Comment: @k.ken well you're dealing with Scalable Vector Graphics, so you shouldn't feel this option of dynamic width/heights is something to be avoided. Your image is going to scale and look as good if you shrink it or increase it's size.

Comment: I have tried every possible solution I find. It's a frustrating. Would you like a closer look at my code?

Comment: @k.ken, sure it'd be interesting to see, post it in a fiddle somewhere and send me a link wilde.morgan@gmail.com

Comment: I generated svg from Graphviz dot. Copying the svg content to my xwiki page and simply change the size using `<svg width="100%" height="100%"></svg>` works for me.

Comment: @MorganWilde nice in theory. In practice small svgs can look blurry and common advice seems to be to resize them to match the render size.

Answer (score -1):

I found it easier to remove the `width` and the `height` attributes and apply pixel dimensions from a wrapper div, e.g.

```
<div style="width: 48px; height: 48px;">
  <svg xmlns="..." viewBox="..."></svg>
</div>
```