# how to increase the size of an SVG file with HTML

Tags: html, image, svg

I created an SVG image with Inkscape and i can't make it bigger using HTML
THE SVG WAS CREATED OUTSIDE OF THE *HTML*, NOT IN THE *HTML* CODE ITSELF, I DID NOT USE
< SVG > TAGS
I used an < img > tag

```
<img src='images/picture.svg' \/>
```

Comment: whoa now... no need to shout.  Did you export it as a png or did you keep it as svg?  Also, the code where you include the image would be nice to see.

Comment: I haven't personally worked with svgs in HTML before but maybe this answer will help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3120739/resizing-svg-in-html Sorry I can't be of more help than that.  (Also as a side note, you have a misplaced `\` character in your img tag)

Comment: @VinnieCaprarola - You can answer your own question (you might have to wait a day or two), so make sure you post it as an answer, and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just style it like you would any other image. So something like this should work:

```
img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: i tried this, it makes the area (whitespace) around the image bigger, but not the image itself, and the whitespace just takes up space

Answer (score 0):

Step 1) Make the SVG element on the page—however you have embedded it, be it inline `<svg>`, `<img>`, `<object>` or `<embed>`—the size that you want it to be.

Step 2) Set the [`viewBox` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SVG/Attribute/viewBox) on your SVG element to define what content area should be scaled to fill the space.