# Resize an SVG to 100% of its parent width and keep its aspect ratio

Tags: css, svg

I'd like to have an SVG image that has the width of its parent div and the height should be 14% of its width.

This code works in Firefox but not in Chrome:

```
<svg 
    xml:space="preserve"
    preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"
    height="100%" width="100%"
    viewBox="-1 -10 242 33">
    ...
</svg>
```

In Chrome the aspect ratio is 1 so the svg content is at the top of the square with a lot of whitespace below it.
I need the svg file to be inline so I can't use the `img` tag.

Comment: [This has been answered already.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3120739/1679849) Just delete `height="100%" width="100%"` from the `<svg>` tag.

Comment: That makes the svg disapper completely.

Comment: Then you probably haven't assigned a width to the parent container.

Comment: The parent is a `col-md-12` bootstrap calss and has the width 100%.

Answer (score 3):

If you remove the `height` and `width` attributes from your SVG but retain the `viewBox`, then it will scale proportionally to the size of its parent container. For example, the following markup produces three SVG images in `<div>` containers of different widths. In each case, the SVG scales up to the width of its parent container.

This is working fine for me in Chrome.

```html
<div style="width:200px; height:100px; background-color:#f00; margin-bottom:10px;">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 70 10">
    <rect x="1" y="1" width="68" height="8" fill="#ff0" stroke="none" />
    <text x="35" y="7" font-size="6" text-anchor="middle">&lt;SVG&gt; width=200px</text
  </svg>
</div>
<div style="width:300px; height:100px; background-color:#f00; margin-bottom:10px;">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 70 10">
    <rect x="1" y="1" width="68" height="8" fill="#ff0" stroke="none" />
    <text x="35" y="7" font-size="6" text-anchor="middle">&lt;SVG&gt; width=300px</text
  </svg>
</div>
<div style="width:400px; height:100px; background-color:#f00; margin-bottom:10px;">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 70 10">
    <rect x="1" y="1" width="68" height="8" fill="#ff0" stroke="none" />
    <text x="35" y="7" font-size="6" text-anchor="middle">&lt;SVG&gt; width=400px</text
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: [Here is an example that uses your code](http://marian42.de/svg/). It works in FF but not in Chrome.

Comment: @Toast Well that looks absolutely fine to me. I think what you need to do is this: (1) Create a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the markup that is causing this problem, (2) paste this markup in your question instead of linking to an off-site web page, and (3) take screenshots of the expected behaviour and the incorrect behaviour you're seeing in Chrome, and insert them in your question.

Comment: How can I put the files required by bootstrap in my question? If I don't provide them, the code is not runnable...

Comment: @Toast Can't you just link then in? Why is this a problem?

Comment: From where should I link them? It's a problem because the example is either incomplete or it contains all the css code of bootstrap.

Comment: @Toast From your HTML, where else?? JSFiddle has a button that allows you to add external resources. So does the snippet editor built into this website. Sorry, but I've had a pretty tiring day and don't have the patience for this right now. Hopefully someone else can fix your problems for you.

Comment: First sentence <3