# Resizing SVG in HTML

Tags: html, svg

I found this question [Resizing SVG in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3120739/609290) but the answer (removing the `<svg>` `width` and `height` attributes and resizing the `viewBox` attribute) doesn't correctly rescale my SVG file.

It's a logo file that I purchased from [Looka](https://looka.com) and I'd like to begin using it but I'm stumped as to how to rescale|resize it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  version="1.1"
  width="3171.4285714285716"
  height="2645.5238095238096"
  viewBox="0 -25.714285714285715 3171.4285714285716 2645.5238095238096">
   <rect fill="#67b231" width="3171.4285714285716" height="2645.5238095238096" />
   <g transform="scale(8.571428571428571) translate(10, 10)">
      <defs id="SvgjsDefs2369" />
      <g transform="matrix(...)"></g>
      <g transform="matrix(...)"></g>
      <g transform="matrix(...)"></g>
   </g>
</svg>
```

If I remove the `<svg>` `width` and `height`, the `viewBox` retains the size.

If I also then reduce the `viewBox`, the image retains the same size, I assume (!?) because the child `<rect>` contains `width` and `height` attributes too.

But, if I remove the `<rect>` `width` and `height` attributes, the result is similarly-sized whitespace (and no logo).

1. How should I approach arbitrarily rescaling|resizing the image?
2. Should I preserve the `width`:`height` ratio when I adjust the `viewBox`?
3. Should the `viewBox` have a positive y-position (currently `-25.714...`)?

Comment: is the svg inlined in your html or as an `img` tag?

Comment: How do you want it to appear? Note that if you want to preserve the aspect ratio you need a viewBox.

Comment: @Sysix I had it inlined (not wrapped by an `img` tag). @robert-longson thank you!

Comment: You are throwing spaghetti against the wall and hoping something sticks. You need to learn how svg works instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this as a useful snippet. Without editing the `<svg>` code at all I've set it up so that you can wrap any `<svg>` in a div with class of svgSize like this:

`<div class="svgSize"><svg>...</svg></div>`

Then using an inline style you can pass either `--svgHeight` or `--svgWidth` using whatever value you wish, so for example `--svgHeight: 100px` and the SVG will resize to the value given while keeping it's aspect ratio. If you don't pass either value it will default to auto which will resize to fill the parent

Gotta love CSS Custom Properties

```css
.svgSize {
  display: inline-flex;
  height: var(--svgHeight, auto);
  width: var(--svgWidth, auto);
}
.svgSize svg {
  height: auto; width: auto;
  max-height: 100%; max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="svgSize" style="--svgWidth: 5rem">
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <svg
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    version="1.1"
    width="3171.4285714285716"
    height="2645.5238095238096"
    viewBox="0 -25.714285714285715 3171.4285714285716 2645.5238095238096">
     <rect fill="#67b231" width="3171.4285714285716" height="2645.5238095238096" />
     <g transform="scale(8.571428571428571) translate(10, 10)">
        <defs id="SvgjsDefs2369" />
        <g transform="matrix(...)"></g>
        <g transform="matrix(...)"></g>
        <g transform="matrix(...)"></g>
     </g>
  </svg>
</div>

<div class="svgSize" style="--svgHeight: 15rem">
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <svg
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    version="1.1"
    width="3171.4285714285716"
    height="2645.5238095238096"
    viewBox="0 -25.714285714285715 3171.4285714285716 2645.5238095238096">
     <rect fill="#67b231" width="3171.4285714285716" height="2645.5238095238096" />
     <g transform="scale(8.571428571428571) translate(10, 10)">
        <defs id="SvgjsDefs2369" />
        <g transform="matrix(...)"></g>
        <g transform="matrix(...)"></g>
        <g transform="matrix(...)"></g>
     </g>
  </svg>
</div>

<div class="svgSize" style="">
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <svg
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    version="1.1"
    width="3171.4285714285716"
    height="2645.5238095238096"
    viewBox="0 -25.714285714285715 3171.4285714285716 2645.5238095238096">
     <rect fill="#67b231" width="3171.4285714285716" height="2645.5238095238096" />
     <g transform="scale(8.571428571428571) translate(10, 10)">
        <defs id="SvgjsDefs2369" />
        <g transform="matrix(...)"></g>
        <g transform="matrix(...)"></g>
        <g transform="matrix(...)"></g>
     </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll try this in the morning.

Comment: Apologies for not having marked this as the answer sooner.